# Finding the source of an error on sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I am running a job in the background with sidekiq and using perform_later with rails 5.1.7.

Right now in the sidekiq dashboard I am getting an error related to a method, but I am calling that method more than once, so I don't know where exactly is the problem coming from.

If I use **perform_now** it works, but not with **perform_later**

In the "retry" section of the dashboard I am getting for this job the following error:

```
 NameError: undefined local variable or method `payload' for #<AppServices::BookingService
```

Comment: The dashboard can show full backtrace by clicking time field such as  ```several minutes ago```.Or you can find backtrace from your woker log

Comment: is there a way to debug it? the line is giving me for the error, does not content that method

Comment: Async job is hard to debug. Make sure you have log statement around key step, and you can test its logic with rspec.The backtrace only show the line?

Comment: I finally found the problem. I had no env keys set for stripe in the active job class. But sidekiq was pointing me to some non related function, and giving me a random error, for some reason that I did not get to understand...

Comment: If you want to find the resaon why sidekiq lead to this problem you can put your code here